# PHP Wordpress Look up user-role for logged in user, add to page class

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

Wordpress PHP:
I am in need of a small php script that allows me to check for the userrole of the active logged in user. And to output it as a class item.

I have assigned User Roles via Ultimate Member - if that has anything to say.

Example:
A user is a member of a role, named: "storeowner".
I would like to add that to a div as a shortcode of sorts.

Is there a quick and dirty solution out there ?
Sorry if this has been asked and answered, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Worked on something like this a while back feel free to use my repo. https://github.com/amarinediary/User-Activity-Monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper function to return a space separated list of user roles "role1 role2 role3":

```php
function my_get_role_classnames($uid) {
    $user_meta = get_userdata($uid);
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    return implode(" ", $user_roles);
}
```

Then use like so:

```html
class="<?php echo my_get_role_classnames(1); ?>"
```

Comment: thank you for the input. I do however not require to check for a spesific role I want to output the current role as html text.

      class=" .' + <? $user_roles ?>+ ' "

Comment: updated my answer to get the roles as a string for classnames.

Comment: thank you for your help. I got it working. Except for one little annoying thing. Ultimate Member adds the pretext "um-" before every Role ID. Your code retrieves the Role ID - is it possible to get the Role Name in stead ?